# Android best logger for logging into file

Tags: android, logging, slf4j, noclassdeffounderror

What is the best logger framework which perfectly use in Android system for logging text into file?

I tried to use SLF4J-android but I got an exception

```
04-29 12:58:57.604: E/AndroidRuntime(372): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.slf4j.LoggerFactory
```

here is my code:

```
public class Main extends TabActivity {
    private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(Main.class);
```

I added the slf4j-android-1.6.1-RC1.jar into build path

What will be the problem?

Answer (score 17):

`slf4j-android` only supports logging to `logcat` and thus omits several classes from the regular SLF4J jar. If you want to use logback to log to a file, you need the [API jar](http://search.maven.org/remotecontent?filepath=org/slf4j/slf4j-api/1.7.5/slf4j-api-1.7.5.jar) (not `slf4j-android`) and [`logback-android`](http://tony19.github.com/logback-android/). You're looking for the [`FileAppender`](http://logback.qos.ch/manual/appenders.html#FileAppender) or [`RollingFileAppender`](http://logback.qos.ch/manual/appenders.html#RollingFileAppender).

### Instructions:

1. Add `slf4j-api-<version>.jar` and `logback-android-<version>.jar` to your classpath.
2. Create the file `assets/logback.xml` in your project (or use the `AndroidManifest.xml`...see [example](http://tony19.github.com/logback-android/)), containing the following configuration:

```
<configuration>
  <appender name="FILE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.FileAppender">
    <file>/sdcard/testFile.log</file>
    <append>true</append>
    <encoder>
      <pattern>%-4relative [%thread] %-5level %logger{35} - %msg%n</pattern>
    </encoder>
  </appender>
        
  <root level="DEBUG">
    <appender-ref ref="FILE" />
  </root>
</configuration>
```

*Note: Since the specified path is on SD, make sure to use [`WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html#WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) permission. You can instead specify a different path where you already have write permissions.*

Your Java code, which contains the SLF4J logging calls, now logs all events at or above the `DEBUG` level to the `/sdcard/testFile.log`.

Answer (score 2):

Make a folder named "libs" and put the jar inside that folder.