# how to write android.util.Log into a plain file on SDCard in android

Tags: android, logging

Hey guys I have created an app and provided to people to use it. They cater different issues in the app. I want to capture all Log activities in the file so that they can give it to me and i can examine the problem. i have searched on internet but not getting clear answer. Can any one tell me how can i redirect `Android.util.Log` output to a text file.

I have tried this
`File filename = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/gridlog.log");

filename.createNewFile();

String cmd = "logcat -d -f " + filename.getAbsolutePath();

Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd);`

now to capture Log in file i used

`Log.e("HEY ERROR", "HEY THIS IS ERROR");`

but it store lot of irrelavant information in the file..and also i works only ones, later if i want to Log info or error it is not capturing it.

Can any android guru help me here.. Thanks

Comment: Try [`logback-android`](http://tony19.github.com/logback-android/) (see similar [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11920403/1200334))

Answer (score 1):

If you want to remotly receieve notifications & error's log / crash reports you can use free services like :
[AppHance](http://www.apphance.com/)
[BugSense](http://www.bugsense.com/)
(I am sure you can find more free service over the web..)

To write the log to SD Card and than to transfer it manually it is not a very clever solution when you have this free cross platform services in my opinion.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

A wee bit too late to answer but might help folks in the future. [TestFlight's](http://www.testflight.com) pretty cool free service that allows remote logging, crash reports, beta rollouts, to name a few. Needless to say, these activities can be monitored from your testflight dashboard.  Also, supports iOS as well as Android.